# bash Shell: lost first element data partially

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, centos

**Using bash shell:**
I am trying to read a file line by line.
and every line contains two meaning full file names delimited by ``` "``" ```

**file:1 image_config.txt**

```
bbbbb.mp4``thumb/hashdata.gif
bbbbb.mp4``thumb/hashdata2.gif
```

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="image_config.txt"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

IFS='``' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
if [ "$line" = "" ]; then
echo lineempty
else

file=${array[0]}
hash=${array[2]}

    echo $file$hash;
    output=$(ffmpeg -v warning -ss 2 -t 0.8 -i $file -vf scale=200:-1 -gifflags +transdiff -y $hash);
    echo $output;
#    echo ${array[0]}${array[1]}${array[2]}
fi;

done < "$filename"
```

first time executed successfully but when loop executes second time.
variable `file` lost `bbbbb` from `bbbbb.mp4`
and following output comes out

**Output :**

```
user@domain [~/public_html/Videos]$ sh imager.sh 
bbbbb.mp4thumb/hashdata.gif

.mp4thumb/hashdata2.gif
.mp4: No such file or directory

lineempty
```

Comment: While your code appears to be overly complex, I don't get this output when I run the code with this data, the filenames are reported correctly.  Have you tried running it with `bash -x` ?  By the way, you have tagged `bash` but when you run it you use `sh`, not bash.  Be careful of that you might get different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out [Bash FAQ 89 - I'm using a loop which runs once per line of input but it only seems to run once; everything after the first line is ignored?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) which seems to be helpful in your case.

---

**Aside:**

There is no point in using the same character twice in `IFS`.

```
IFS=\`
```

Is enough.

Check out this:

```
var='abc``def'
IFS=\`\` read -ra arr <<< "$var"
printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

*Output:*

```
<abc>
<>
<def>
```

As you can see, `arr[0]` is `abc`, `arr[1]` is **empty** and `arr[2]` is `def`, and not `arr[0]` is `abc` and `arr[1]` is `def` as one might expect.

Taken from the [IFS wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) of [Greycat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/GreyCat) and [Lhunath](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Lhunath) [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) :

> The IFS variable is used in shells (Bourne, POSIX, ksh, bash) as the input field separator (or internal field separator). **Essentially, it is a string of special characters which are to be treated as delimiters between words/fields when splitting a line of input**.

Comment: Thanks  @Rany i just placed   'output=$(ffmpeg -v warning -ss 2 -t 0.8 -i $file -vf scale=200:-1 -gifflags +transdiff -y $hash </dev/null); ' replacing   'output=$(ffmpeg -v warning -ss 2 -t 0.8 -i $file -vf scale=200:-1 -gifflags +transdiff -y $hash ' and it worked for me

Comment: Actually the problem was with ffmpeg execution due to some I/O problems

Comment: Cool :-) Glad to  hear it worked for you. Did the FAQ was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do differently, avoiding a read in the read:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="image_config.txt"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  if [ "$line" = "" ]; then
    echo lineempty
  else

  file=$( echo ${line} | awk -F \` ' { print $1 } ' )
  hash=$( echo ${line} | awk -F \` ' { print $3 } ' )

      echo $file$hash;
      output=$(ffmpeg -v warning -ss 2 -t 0.8 -i $file -vf scale=200:-1 -gifflags +transdiff -y $hash);
      echo $output;
  fi;

done < "$filename"
```